# Matlab Iris Classification input size mistmach

Tags: matlab, input, classification

I am very new to Matlab. What i am trying to do is classify the iris dataset using Cross-Validation (that means that i have to split the dataset in 3: trainingSet, validationSet, and test set) . In my mind everything i write here is ok (beeing a beginner is hard sometimes). So i could use a little help...

This is the function that splits the data (first 35(70% of the data) are the training set, the rest is the validation set(15%) and 15% i will use later for the test set)

```
close all; clear ;
load fisheriris;

for i = 1:35
    for j = 1:4
        trainSeto(i,j) = meas(i,j);
    end
end
for i = 51:85
    for j = 1:4
        trainVers(i-50,j) = meas(i,j);
    end
end
for i = 101:135
    for j = 1:4
        trainVirg(i-100,j) = meas(i,j);
    end
end
for i = 36:43
    for j = 1:4
        valSeto(i-35,j) = meas(i,j);
    end
end
for i = 86:93
    for j = 1:4
        valVers(i-85,j) = meas(i,j);
    end
end
for i = 136:143
    for j = 1:4
        valVirg(i-135,j) = meas(i,j);
    end
end
for i = 44:50
    for j = 1:4
        testSeto(i-43,j) = meas(i,j);
    end
end
for i = 94:100
    for j = 1:4
        testVers(i-93,j) = meas(i,j);
    end
end
for i = 144:150
    for j = 1:4
        testVirg(i-143,j) = meas(i,j);
    end
end
```

And this is the main script:

```
close all; clear;
%%the 3 tipes of iris
run divinp

% the representation of the 3 classes(their coding)
a = [-1 -1 +1]';
b = [-1 +1 -1]';
c = [+1 -1 -1]';

%training set
trainInp = [trainSeto trainVers trainVirg];

%the targets
T = [repmat(a,1,length(trainSeto)) repmat(b,1,length(trainVers)) repmat(c,1,length(trainVirg))];

%%the training

trainCor = zeros(10,10);
valCor = zeros(10,10);
Xn = zeros(1,10);
Yn = zeros(1,10);

for k = 1:10,
    Yn(1,k) = k; 
    for n = 1:10,
        Xn(1,n) = n;
        net = newff(trainInp,T,[k n],{},'trainbfg');
        net = init(net);
        net.divideParam.trainRatio = 1;
        net.divideParam.valRatio = 0;
        net.divideParam.testRatio = 0;
        net.trainParam.max_fail = 2;

        valInp = [valSeto valVers valVirg];
        valT = [repmat(a,1,length(valSeto)) repmat(b,1,length(valVers)) repmat(c,1,length(valVirg))];

        [net,tr] = train(net,trainInp,T);

        Y = sim(net,trainInp);

        [Yval,Pfval,Afval,Eval,perfval] = sim(net,valInp,[],[],valT);

        % calculate [%] of correct classifications
        trainCor(k,n) = 100 * length(find(T.*Y > 0)) / length(T);
        valCor(k,n) = 100 * length(find(valT.*Yval > 0)) / length(valT);
        end
        end
        figure
        surf(Xn,Yn,trainCor/3);
        view(2)
        figure
        surf(Xn,Yn,valCor/3);
        view(2)
```

I get this error

> Error using trainbfg (line 120) Inputs and targets have different
>   numbers of samples.
>
> Error in network/train (line 106) [net,tr] =
>   feval(net.trainFcn,net,X,T,Xi,Ai,EW,net.trainParam);
>
> Error in ClassIris (line 38)
>           [net,tr] = train(net,trainInp,T);

```
close all; clear ;
load fisheriris;

trainSetoIndx = 1:35;
trainVersIndx = 51:85;   % or: trainVersIndx = trainSetoIndx + 50;
trainVirgIndx = 101:135;

colIndx = 1:4;

trainSeto = meas(trainSetoIndx, colIndx);
trainVers = meas(trainVersIndx, colIndx);
trainVirg = meas(trainVirgIndx, colIndx);

valSetoIndx = 36:43;
valVersIndx = 86:93;
valVirgIndx = 136:143

valSeto = meas(valSetoIndx, colIndx);
valVers = meas(valVersIndx, colIndx);
valVirg = meas(valVirgIndx, colIndx);

testSetoIndx = 44:50;
testVersIndx = 94:100;
testVirgIndx = 144:150

testSeto = meas(testSetoIndx, colIndx);
testVers = meas(testVersIndx, colIndx);
testVirg = meas(testVirgIndx, colIndx);
```

i have writen it with ":" also still the same problem it's something with repmat.. i don't know how to use it properly or newff :D

Comment: Learn to use array subscripts (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/colon.html ) to get rid of all those nasty loops, and learn how to debug (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/debugging-code.html ).  If it says "Inputs and targets have different numbers of samples.", then you should check what the size of your "inputs" and "targets" are and whether that corresponds to the requirements of the function(s) you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you started, you can rewrite your code loops as follows:

```
trainSetoIndx = 1:35;
trainVersIndx = 51:85;   % or: trainVersIndx = trainSetoIndx + 50;
trainVirgIndx = 101:135; % or: trainVirgIndx = trainSetoIndx + 100;

colIndx = 1:4; % can't tell if this is all the columns in meas

trainSeto = meas(trainIndx, colIndx);
trainVers = meas(trainVersIndx, colIndx);
trainVirg = meas(trainVirgIndx, colIndx);
```

The do the same thing for all the others:

```
valSetoIndx = 36:43;
```

etc.

Next, simply type `whos` at the command prompt and you will see the sizes of all the arrays you have created. See whether the ones that need to be the same size have, in fact, the same dimensions.

Comment: yes meas is 150x4 :D . trainInp is 35x12 and T is 3 x 105. same thing, it's not a problem with those fors... i think it's from repmat or something in my thought process there

Comment: i have attached the code writen as you suggested :D

Comment: As code gets cleaner, it will become easier to debug. Now explain what you want the size / contents of your variables to be - in particular, `T`. Then show what they actually are. This will help figure out whether `repmat` is the problem.

Comment: in T i want to store the desired output for every entry in trainInp, so i can train the network :D . so for every entry in trainInp, i must have a 3x1 matrix in T . Or that's what i am trying to achieve . I documented myself from http://lab.fs.uni-lj.si/lasin/wp/IMIT_files/neural/doc/seminar8.pdf it's exactly what i have to do so i am trying to figure it out . That's what i understood the guy wanted to do

Comment: I think the problem may be that you have made `trainSeto` etc. of size (35x4). Draw a picture for yourself of the sizes of each of the parts that make up the matrix, and you will see what I mean.

Comment: i should make it 35 x 3 ? Beucase i've tried adding 1 extra digit to a b or c yet... ok let me try painting on a sheet of paper !

Comment: you can call me stupid but T is something like col 1 = 1 2 3 col 2 = 1 2 3 col 3 = 1 2 3 etc and trainSeto is something like col 1 = 1 2 3.... 50 col 2 = 1 2 3.... 50 .So i kinda see your point but when i add T' still the same thing :(

Comment: When I run your code, I get an error saying that the target needs to have 12 columns - when in fact you are passing a 3 x 105 element array. Think about why it wants 12 columns - I think that's four 3 different types of iris and 4 different measurements.

Comment: yes you are indeed right but i don't know how i could remake that 35x4 ... i mean i read what i gave you but there is nothing said about that divinp from his code... i tried to remake it but the result is what you see :(